# Managing connected js and css assets in grails using asset-pipeline plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

In resources plugin it was possible to define a tagname which had references to both css and js files. For example:

```
jScrollPane {
    resource url:[file:'jscrollpane.min.js']
    resource url:[file:'mousewheel.js']
    resource url:[file:'jscrollpane.css']
}
```

This allowed to import all files using just `<r:require module="jScrollPane" />`

This library always requires the same js and css files. It is not DRY to define on every page import to js and css manifests separately. Is it possible to define a manifest with both css and js? If not, is there any other way this can be achieved?

thanks, droggo

Comment: What do you mean by define on every page? Don't you use a common layout that defines your assets? In that case you do not have to repeat yourself.

Comment: We have a big application and including every JS and every CSS file on every page is not possible. We need every page to define it's resources

Comment: Well then I would keep using `resources` plugin. The `asset-pipeline` plugin uses a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discussed this more here: https://github.com/bertramdev/asset-pipeline/issues/132

Basically we have created simple taglib:

```
def lib = { attrs -> 
    out << asset.javascript(src:"${attrs.src}.js")
    out << asset.stylesheet(src:"${attrs.src}.css")
}
```

which can include both assets with one tag.